# Jquery lavaLamp navigation link

Tags: jquery

Is there a lavalamp jquery plugin like this, the background element doesn't follow mouse unless clicked the menu. 
I've been searching a while couldnt find one, or my "keywords" wrong.

My code is working fine, but just wondering if any option could do that.

thanks in advance.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#lavalamp").lavaLamp({
                fx: "easeinout",
                speed: 700,
             click: function(event, menuItem) {
                   return false;
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
```

HTML

```
<ul id="lavalamp" class="nav">
<li><a href="#a">Menu1</a></li>  
<li><a href="#b">Menu2</a></li> 
<li><a href="#c">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you please post your codes?

Answer (score 0):

menu is made for navigating to a specific url, cliking that link will redirect to a new page and the lavalamp animation will not have the time to execute or it will be distroyed